# How to customize a longpress directive using rxjs in Vue or other frameworks?

Tags: vue.js, rxjs

I am trying to write a `longpresss` or `longtouch` directive in `Vue`.
Here is my code, but it will emit `console.log('startObser')` after every touch.

And if there's a `touchmove` event, `console.log('startObser')` would emitted too.

```js
  inserted: (el, binding) => {
    console.log(el);
    touchstartSub = fromEvent(el, 'touchstart');
    touchendSub = fromEvent(el, 'touchend');

    startObser = touchstartSub.pipe(
      mergeMap(e =>
        of(e).pipe(
          delay(2000),
          takeUntil(touchendSub),
        ),
      ),
    );

    startObser.subscribe((e) => {
      console.log('startObser');
      if (typeof binding.value === 'function') {
        binding.value(e);
      }
    });
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

try the following, i used mouseup and mousedown but you can replace it with touch. THis observable chain will only fire when hold own mouse and release after 2000ms

```
const touchstart = fromEvent(document, 'mousedown');
const touchend = fromEvent(document, 'mouseup');
touchstart.pipe(
    switchMap(()=>touchend),
    timeInterval(),
    filter(time=>time.interval>2000))
.subscribe(console.log)
```